# How can i find the max value of a group of lineseries

Tags: apache-flex

I need to recalculate the max value of lineChart according to the visible lineseries.
In the application i have the ability to make visible or not the lineseries of the graph and if i make not visible the lineseries with the actual top value i want to zoom in and change the top value of the graph.

Anyone knows how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer.

In this post
http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2009/10/linechart-with-checkbox-legend.html
I have found all the code i needed.

Claudio